# How to set the task switcher icon text?

Tags: swt

In my SWT application I want to set the OS task switcher (Alt-Tab) icon and its text caption. Setting the icon works OK, but its caption while Alt-Tab switching among apps is always "SWT", not the String I set it to.

I'm primarily interested in this working in Linux (Ubuntu), but it should work cross-platform as SWT, right?

```java
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setImage
(new Image (display, loadSvgImage().scaledTo(500, 500)));
shell.setText("SuperApp");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the application name. You set it with `Display.setAppName` which must be called **before** you create the display:

```java
Display.setAppName("appname");

Display display = new Display();
```